# Adjusting Table Widths

Tags: tables, width, textwidth

Quick question: how do I make sure that all three tables have the same width? Ideally the entire page with, without modifying the content of the input files:

```
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\caption{} \vspace{-.2cm}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off, width=0.9\linewidth}

\label{table_firststage} 

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth} 
{\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}  
\input{Tables/tab_fs.tex}}  
\end{subtable} 
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth} 
{\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8.5pt}   \vspace{2mm}
\input{Tables/tab_rf.tex}}  \end{subtable} 
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth} 
{\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}   \vspace{2mm}
\input{Tables/tab_2sls.tex}} 
\end{subtable}

\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off, width=0.9\linewidth} \vspace{-2mm} 
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
 \scriptsize \raggedright \hspace{22pt}
\input{Tables/PanelD.tex} 
\end{subtable} 
\end{center}
\normalsize 
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
    {\footnotesize \textbf{Notes:} }
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please tell us more about the contents of the files `tab_fs.tex`, `tab_rf.tex`, `tab_2sls.tex`, and `PanelD.tex`.

Comment: Hi @Mico Thanks for the reply. This is what the content looks like:
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} \subcaption*{Panel A: First stage} \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}} \hline\hline
                &\multicolumn{4}{c}{log recruits p.c.}                                      \\\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
  Here reg results
\hline\hline \end{tabular}

Comment: The width of a `tabular` environment is *not* determined by the width of the encasing `subtable` or `minipage` environment. (Aside: A `subtable` environment is nothing but a `minipage` environment that's been told what to do if a `\caption` statement is encountered.) If you want to fix the overall width of the table (to, say, `\textwidth`), you should be employing `tabular*` or `tabularx` (or similar) environments, *not* `tabular` environments.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I haven't quite understood it, but does it mean that I have to change the content of the input files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible without touching your files, provided that the contents of your files are similar enough that is (the following disables `\subcaption` during trial runs, you might need to disable more commands).

First we have to think of what we can do to achieve the goal. The options we have are:

- scaling font sizes (**bad** idea, this gives inconsistent sizing throughout your document)
- scaling the `\tabcolsep` (still bad, the result looks awful, but better than resizing font sizes)

This here implements the latter with a small loop. As I said, the result looks awful, but it's workable at least for the small MWE I clubbed together from your fragments. Still I don't really recommend this, I coded it merely for the act of coding it, nothing more.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname1.tex}
\subcaption*{Panel A: First stage}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
  \hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{log recruits and things p.c.} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
  Here reg results \\
  \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname2.tex}
\subcaption*{Panel B: Second stage}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
  \hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{log recruits p.c.} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4567) \\
  Here reg results \\
  \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname3.tex}
\subcaption*{Panel C: Third stage}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
  \hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{log recruits p.c.} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  & (1) & (2) & (three is a number, I guess) & (4) \\
  Here reg results \\
  \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname4.tex}
\subcaption*{Panel D: Fourth stage}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
  \hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{log recruits p.c.} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
  Here reg results and a bit of more text \\
  \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@gobblethree[3]{}
\newdimen\tabscaler@maxresiduum
\tabscaler@maxresiduum=100sp % must be at moste 100sp off
\newdimen\tabscaler@target
\newdimen\tabscaler@last
\newdimen\tabscaler@this
\newdimen\tabscaler@tcs@last
\newdimen\tabscaler@tcs@this
\newcount\tabscaler@loops
\protected\def\tabscaler@trialrun#1%
  {%
    \tabcolsep=#1\relax
    % this is exactly as wide as the last used tabcolsep, so reduce it a bit
    \ifdim\tabcolsep=\tabscaler@tcs@this
      \advance\tabcolsep-1sp
    \fi
    \tabscaler@last=\tabscaler@this
    \tabscaler@tcs@last=\tabscaler@tcs@this
    \tabscaler@tcs@this=\tabcolsep
    \sbox\z@{\input{\tabscaler@name}\unskip}%
    \tabscaler@this=\wd\z@
  }
\protected\def\tabscaler@loop
  {%
    \advance\tabscaler@loops\@ne
    \typeout{tabscaler loop: \the\tabscaler@loops}%
    % break criteria:
    %   1. The table is not bigger than target
    %   2. Residuum is below \tabscaler@maxresiduum
    \ifdim\tabscaler@this>\tabscaler@target
    \else
      \ifdim\dimexpr\tabscaler@target-\tabscaler@this<\tabscaler@maxresiduum
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobblethree
      \fi
    \fi
    \tabscaler@trialrun
      {%
        \fpeval
          {%
            (\tabscaler@target - \tabscaler@last)
            / (\tabscaler@this - \tabscaler@last)
            * (\tabscaler@tcs@this - \tabscaler@tcs@last)
            + \tabscaler@tcs@last
          }%
        pt%
      }%
    \tabscaler@loop
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \tabscaler { O{\linewidth} m }
  {%
    \begingroup
      \tabscaler@target=\dimexpr#1\relax
      \edef\tabscaler@name{\unexpanded{#2}}%
      % locally disable \subcaption
      \RenewDocumentCommand\subcaption{som}{\ignorespaces}%
      \tabscaler@tcs@this=-1pt % or else the z@ point isn't correct
      \tabscaler@trialrun\z@
      \ifdim\tabscaler@this>\tabscaler@target
        \PackageError{tabscaler}
          {Target dimension is smaller than natural width}
          {Giving up on this. Make your table smaller.}%
      \fi
      \tabscaler@trialrun\p@
      \tabscaler@loops=\z@
      \loop\ifdim\tabscaler@this=\tabscaler@last
        \advance\tabscaler@loops\@ne
        \typeout{tabscaler preloop: \the\tabscaler@loops}%
        \tabscaler@trialrun{10\tabscaler@tcs@this}%
      \repeat
      \tabscaler@loop
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \expandafter
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\tabcolsep\the\tabcolsep\relax
      \input{#2}%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\caption{}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off, width=0.9\linewidth}

\label{table_firststage}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
{\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}\tabscaler{\jobname1}\par}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
{\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8.5pt}   \vspace{2mm}
\tabscaler{\jobname2}}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
{\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}   \vspace{2mm}
\tabscaler{\jobname3}}
\end{subtable}

\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off, width=0.9\linewidth} \vspace{-2mm}
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
 \scriptsize \raggedright \hspace{22pt}
\tabscaler{\jobname4}
\end{subtable}
\end{center}
\normalsize
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    {\footnotesize \textbf{Notes:} }
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]